# Kernel panic on raspberrypi zero dtoverlay with poweroff

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

On a pi zero 1.1 with bullseye lite and camera B rev 2 I set

> dtoverlay=gpio-poweroff,gpiopin=17

That works, GPIO17 goes high after halt.
But it produces a kernel panic.

Setting only

> dtoverlay=gpio-poweroff

works without kernel panic, but the default GPIO26 is not affected.

Same result on a pi2 v1.1
Same result on a pi3+ without camera

How can I fix that?

screen of kernel panic:
[image: Monitor of kernel panic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Name:   gpio-poweroff

Info:   Drives a GPIO high or low on poweroff (including halt). Using this
        overlay interferes with the normal power-down sequence, preventing the
        kernel from resetting the SoC (a necessary step in a normal power-off
        or reboot). This also disables the ability to trigger a boot by driving
        GPIO3 low.

        The GPIO starts in an inactive state. At poweroff time it is driven
        active for 100ms, then inactive for 100ms, then active again. It is
        safe to remove the power at any point after the initial activation of
        the GPIO.

        Users of this overlay are required to provide an external mechanism to
        switch off the power supply when signalled - failure to do so results
        in a kernel BUG, increased power consumption and undefined behaviour.
```

**Users of this overlay are required to provide an external mechanism to switch off the power supply when signalled - failure to do so results in a kernel BUG**

Comment: I am using suck an external  mechanism with buster and earlier since a long time but newer experienced a kernel panic , or maybe did not look for. thanks for your answer